# Контекстуальные querySelectors не эквивалентны?

Tags: javascript

Тестируя некий код споткнулся на ошибке `Illegal invocation`.
Собственно говоря чтобы выбрать какой-то элемент на странице мы можем воспользоваться DOM API.

Пишем:

```
document.querySelector("body")
```

Вроде все ок в консоли ок - выдает нам то что мы просим.

Однако такой код не работает:

```
let context = document.querySelector("body");
document.querySelector.call(context, "p");
```

Вызывает ту самую ошибку.

И да:

```
let context = document.querySelector("body");
document.querySelector == context.querySelector; /// false
```

Может кто-нибудь пояснить почему querySelectors не равны?

Comment: А почему они должны быть равны? В частности `document` это не `HTMLElement` в отличии от `body`.

Comment: Но, например, у разных DOM элементов `querySelector` один и тот же. `/* html */ document.documentElement.querySelector === /* body */ document.body.querySelector // true`

Comment: Ну не силен в интерфейсах DOM. Предположил что функции должны быть равны так как контекст this теряется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что методы `querySelector` определены отдельно для `HTMLDocument` и для `HTMLElement` после того, как их ветви наследования разошлись на `Node`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: Хмм, вот оно что, я то думал функции определяются динамически для каждого узла.